# Ntfy on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install an NTFY server on AWS EC2. So far it works fine, but on my iPhone I don't receive the push messages. They arrive, but I can see them only in the ntfy app after I refreshed the app.  I am  new to AWS, so maybe it is a network/ https problem. The NTFY server should run on port 81.

I use a server.yml file and I uncommented the line

> upstream-base-url: "https://ntfy.sh"

I also checked that this URL is reachable from AWS,

> curl https://ntfy.sh

returns the website.

> How I start ntfy:
> sudo docker run \
> -v /var/cache/ntfy:/var/cache/ntfy \
> -v /etc/ntfy:/etc/ntfy \
> -p 81:80 \
> -itd \
> binwiederhier/ntfy \
> serve \
> --cache-file /var/cache/ntfy/cache.db